# ASP Route Data attribute in HTML Actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have  a href attribute using anchor tag helper asp-all-route-data. I want to change this to use HTML.ActionLink that has a onclick popup message but not sure how to do it.

I have tried this so far:

```
        @Html.ActionLink("Set as Draft", "SetAsDraft", "Item", new { 
        FromRouteAttribute = "setAsDraftParams" },
                                         new { onclick = "return 
     confirm('Are sure you want to set this Item as a draft?');" })
```

Current a href:

```
   <a asp-area="Admin" title="Set as Draft DOR" asp-controller="Dor" asp- 
   action="SetAsDraft" asp-all-route-data="setAsDraftParams">Set as Draft 
    DOR</a>
```

Variable set in the View:

```
      var setAsDraftParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "id", Model.DraftToView.ItemId.ToString() },
            { "returnViewName", 
        nameof(Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.ItemController.Index) 
       }
        };
```

I expect the HTML.ActionLink to return to the viewname set in the setASDraftParams variable

Comment: setAsDraftParams is a variable? try with @setAsDraftParams

Comment: I set it as variable in the View. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using dictionary, you need to use the right key to get the value. DictionaryVariable[key]

Try with:

```
@Html.ActionLink("AQUI", "Index", "Home", new { FromRouteAttribute = setAsDraftParams["returnViewName"] },
     new { onclick = "return confirm('Are sure you want to set this Item as a draft?');" })
```

Comment: I get a Null exception on this. When I step thru the code and get the action in the Controller the id is null.

Comment: Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks